# Migrating a Mariadb/wordpress site with only .frm files

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysqldump, wordpress

My server crashed. My /home /www and lib/mysql were on a different hard disk so I have all the data. The original server was Debian 9 with Mariadb and an apache webserver. I planned to move to mysql so I have a debian 10 server with mysql. I also have another debian 9 server with Mariadb so that I can use sqldump to move my databases. All my databases moved over fine, except one that was a wordpress database. That directory only has .frm files in it, there are no .MYD or .MYI files. I tried copying them to /var/lib/mysql of the Deb9 server, changed the permissions and ownership. However, mysql dump gives the following error message

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1932: "Table 'dbname.tablename' doesn't exist in engine" when using LOCK enter code here
```

I tried copying them as is to the MYSQL server too, the server did not see the tables. In the MariaDB server command line interface it shows the tables. However when I try to view the contents of any table it says

```
Error 1932 (42S02): Table 'dbname.tablename' doesn't exist in engine
```

I get the same error when I try repair table.

Any ideas on how I can get this moved?

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my issue. Instead of copying only the database folder, I copied the entire /var/lib/mysql folder to the mariadb install. Then I did sqldump on each database and moved them to the mysql server. I'm not sure why the copy of the database folder didn't work but I got all my data back.